# VBA - Conditional Format (Font Size)

Tags: vba, excel

**Purpose:** Conditional Formatting - Font Size

If K19 = "Downpayment Source:" Then  K19 font 10, else 12

If K21 = "Amount:" Then K21 font 10, else 12.

**Trying:**

```html
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set Target = ActiveSheet.Range("K19")


If Target = "Downpayment Source:" Then
With ActiveSheet.Range("K19").Font
.Name = "Arial"
.Size = 10
End With
Else
With ActiveSheet.Range("K19").Font
.Name = "Arial"
.Size = 12
End With
Exit Sub


End Sub
```

This code works, but I don't know how to add K21.

**Another Idea:**

If B3="Purchase" then K19, K21 font size 10, else 12.

Either one would work, I'm just not that experienced with VBA.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `This code works` so change it to `B3`? While it works, it's kinda forced/redundant.

Comment: Your question can be boiled down to "How do I use an If Then statement" or "How can I make a Range refer to multiple cells?" Search for either and you will find your answer.

Comment: Why do you reset Target?

Comment: Why can't you use Conditional Formatting? Why have the VBA?

Comment: @findwindow- It's not gonna work like that because it will change everything in the range regardless and that's not what I need to do.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon - Thanks for the advice looking now and realizing a couple things that I could do

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - Not really sure, new at this. But I always appreciate your help.

Comment: @Bruce Wayne - Conditional Formatting doesn't work with font size.

Comment: Ah, you're right! Sorry, I couldv'e sworn you could (I use it for font color and bold, so figured size would be okay).  Remove the `Set Target = ActiveSheet.Range("K19")` line and it should work if you add your statements for the K21 cell.  What's happening is each time the macro triggers, you're resetting the `Target` to K19.  So even if you change K21, it immediately changes to look in K19.

Comment: wrap it all in (excluding your set target) if target.address="$K$9" then  ....... End if, so it only triggers the code if in the cell you're after#

Comment: What if I wanted them to change back and forth between 10 and 12 depending on B3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addresses the option of changing K19 and K21 when B3 becomes Purchase. Note: This only triggers if B3 changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Purchase" Then
            With ActiveSheet.Range("K19").Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 10
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 10
            End With
        Else
            With ActiveSheet.Range("K19").Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 12
            End With
            With ActiveSheet.Range("K21").Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 12
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```